# w2ui grid RE-rendering issue

Tags: jquery, angularjs, w2ui

I am using w2ui grid (1.4) and angular 1.3.4 trying to render grid in one view.
But at first load grid loaded successfully.But when I change the view grid fails to load throwing some error

```
ERROR: The parameter "name" is not unique. There are other objects already created with the same name (obj: grid).
ERROR: The parameter "name" is not unique. There are other objects already created with the same name (obj: layout).
```

so what is the correct way to load grid successfully everytime.
I cannot change the layout name and grid name.

below is link for plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/HzxZwJ22z2ywYmlchxFM?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you shold destroy the w2ui objects first

```
if(w2ui.hasOwnProperty('layout')){
  w2ui['layout'].destroy();
}
if(w2ui.hasOwnProperty('grid')){
  w2ui['grid'].destroy();
}
```

or reuse them with

```
w2ui.layout.content('left',w2ui['grid'])
```